Issue with Vite in Production Environment on IIS Laravel
I need help with an issue in my production environment using Laravel and Vite. I've been struggling with this for days without success.
Everything worked fine in development mode, and all assets loaded correctly. However, after switching to production mode (running the build command), Vite keeps trying to load assets from the local address.
The most common problems I'm encountering are:
Assets that should be loaded from the build folder are not found.
Incorrect paths, like references to /resources/ instead of /build/.
Attempts to access @vite/client, which is only used in development mode.
Updated the application URL in the .env file to reflect the production environment.
Changed the hot file to point to the correct application address in production.
Verified that the vite.config.js is configured with the server's IP address and the appropriate port.
Ran both npm install and npm run build to ensure all dependencies are installed and assets are properly built.
Environment:
The application is hosted on IIS.
Laravel with Vite is being used.
The assets are generated in the public/build folder.
Error:
When I access the application, I receive 404 (Not Found) errors for resources that should be loaded from the build folder.
Has anyone faced a similar issue or knows how to fix this? I’d greatly appreciate any help! 

If your application is present on /public/build and the application requires /build then please define an http redirection (can be installed as an IIS component) such as:

On IIS Manager Create a /build virtual directory only for the purpose of redirection. On this virtual directory define http redirect setting such as

Redirect requests to destination: http://localhost/public/build
Redirection Behavior: It should be modified is necessary according to your needs. Leave the two options blank for now.
This redirection will redirect every request http://localhost/build/xyz to http://localhost/public/build/xyz. If the URL address or links in the page should not be seen by users as /public/build... then you may use more advanced URL Rewrite Module.

Thank for the help
I did it but:
I was able to access http://172.25.7.100/build/, so the virtual directory redirection is working. However, Vite still tries to fetch resources using the address defined in the hot file, like:
http://[::1]:5173/resources/js/app.js
When I change the address in the hot file to match the app's production URL, for example:
http://172.25.7.100/resources/css/app.css
It still gives a Not Found error.

If your application requires access to http://172.25.7.100/css/app.css and the needed files are at http://172.25.7.100/css/resources/app.css, then another simple redirection can be added for/css  ---> /resources/css . If the the opposite  is needed then /resources/css should be redirected to /css.  For all redirections, an important choice is whether to redirect subdirectories or not. As per the application requirement, it can be checked during http redirection settings (the first option under redirection behaviour)
